# Generate custom error message from makefile with WDK build tools

Tags: windows, wdk

I'm compiling a driver using `build.exe` from the Windows Driver Kit.

The system which builds the drivers needs to have a specific environment variable set. If not, I want build to fail with a custom error message.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

I already tried to output a message to stderr by adding this test to `makefile.inc`:

```
all:
    echo My Custom Error 1>&2
```

But the output doesn't show up and the build process doesn't fail. I do know that the `all` target is executed, as I have tested this by redirecting the output to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution.

F.e.: if you add this to the `makefile.inc`, you will force it to fail:

```
all:
    echo fatal error : Whatever error message you like
```

Please use the exact format (and lower-casing) for the string "fatal error x", where x can be replaced with the message you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
! IF "$(YOUR_ENV_VAR)"=="Your condition"
!     message BUILDMSG: Your message
! ELSE
!     INCLUDE $(NTMAKEENV)\makefile.def
! ENDIF
```

Comment: I finally had some time to test this and the build output is: `error 'message' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. So it doesn't seem to work either.